# what is $\langle 2, x , y\rangle$ in $\mathbb Z[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Can anyone tell me what is $\langle 2 , x , y\rangle $ in $\mathbb Z[x,y]$? I was reading Dummit and Foote. But I got stuck with this notation which was not defined there.

Comment: I presume it is the ideal generated by $2$, $x$ and $y$.

Comment: can you please elaborate ?@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Does $<2 , x , y>$ mean all the polynomials in  $Z[x , y]$which involve 2 , x , y?

Comment: To add to Lord Shark's comment, $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is the set of all polynomials in variables $x,y$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @INDIAN If you don't know what an ideal is or what an ideal generated by these or those elements are, most probably you're trying to understand something you haven't yet studied before. In this case, the ideal $\;\langle 2,x,y\rangle\le\Bbb Z[x,y]\;$ can also be charaterized as the ideal of all elements in $\;\Bbb Z[x,y]\;$ with *even free coefficient*

Comment: I know ideal..But  I can not get the two variable stuffs.. Can you please tell me how $<2 , x, y>$ looks like? Is it all polynomials in $Z[x,y]$whose constant terms are even?@DonAntonio

Comment: How it would be even free? will $2x^2 + y^2 +4$ not be in $<2 , x , y>$?@DonAntonio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element  $\;\omega\in\langle 2,x,y\rangle\;$ looks like

$$\omega=2f(x,y)+xg(x,y)+yh(x,y)\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;f,g,h\in\Bbb Z[x,y]$$

Observe that $\;\omega\;$ as above has even free coefficient, which comes from the addend $\;2f(x,y)\;$ , since the other two addends have each free coefficient equal to zero.

OTOH, if $\;p\in\Bbb Z[x,y]\;$ has even free coefficient, say $\;2k\;$ , then we can write

$$p(x,y)=2k+\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x)y^k\;,\;\;a_k\in\Bbb Z[x]\;,\;\;a_0\;\text{ non-constant with free coefficient zero}\implies$$

$$p(x,y)=k\cdot2+a_0(x)+\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k(x)\right)y^k\in\langle 2,x,y\rangle $$

Answer (score 2):

it is the [ideal generated by these elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Ideal_generated_by_a_set).

In particular, given $a_1, \dots a_n \in R$, we can ask "what is the smallest ideal containing these elements?" I,e: the intersection of all ideals containing these elements.

Specializing to your case, $\langle x\rangle$ consists of all polynomials $x \cdot P(x,y)$ so all polynomials where you can factor out an $x$, and $\langle x,y\rangle$ consists of polynomials $xP(x,y)+yP(x,y)$ so all polynomials made up of just $x,y$ (without constant terms) and so on.

Comment: Can I tell that $<2 , x , y>$ means all the polynomials in  $Z[x , y]$which involve 2 , x , y?@Andres Mejja

Comment: I told $<2 , x, y>$ not $<x , y>$.

Comment: @INDIAN hence the "and so on." You should be able to finish the sentence, otherwise this answer was essentially worthless.